# Getting average sales of all month in a single SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I have this table for Daily Orders:

[image]

This table contains the sales per product per day.

Right now, I'm doing something like this for reading:

```
// Create an empty list that will contain all products
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

try  {
    // create database connection
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();

    // fill list with all products
    SqlDataAdapter MasterItems = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AIMS].[dbo].[MasterItems]", con);
    DataTable tabMasterItems = new DataTable();
    MasterItems.Fill(tabMasterItems);
    foreach (DataRow row in tabMasterItems.Rows)
    {
        Product product = new Product(row["ItemNmbr"].ToString());
        product.Description = row["ItemDesc"].ToString();
        product.Type = row["ItemType"].ToString();
        product.ShWgt = Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemShWgt"]);
        product.Class = row["ItemClass"].ToString();
        product.QtyDec = Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemQtyDec"]);
        products.Add(product);
    }
    MasterItems.Dispose();
    tabMasterItems.Dispose();

    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        // get average orders daily
        SqlDataAdapter DailyOrders = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AIMS].[dbo].[TrxDailyOrders] WHERE ItemNmbr=" + product.No, con);
        DataTable tabDailyOrders = new DataTable();
        DailyOrders.Fill(tabDailyOrders);
        foreach (DataRow row in tabDailyOrders.Rows)
        {       
            // here i would make a list with all orders daily, then take the average from that list... but that's dirty and wrong :(
        }
    }
    DailyOrders.Dispose();
    tabDailyOrders.Dispose();

    // display data in datagridview
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tabDailyOrders;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

So.. As I comment in the code... My idea right now is to make a list with all orders daily, then take the average from that list... but that's dirty and wrong :(

I think there should be a method to get in a single query that information.. as I already have it in the same table and I don't think it's a complicated thing..

How can I get the daily sales average with only 1 single query? Or well... at least make it correctly

Comment: `AVG(OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNmbr, CAST(OrderDt AS date))` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

select avg(orderQTY) over (partition by OrderDT) from TrxDailyOrders